# Android - ConstraintVertical weight in ConstraintLayout doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight, android-layout

I am using from `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="5"`in`ConstraintLayout` but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtComingSoon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E2E4"
        android:text="New Courses Starting Soon.."
        android:textColor="#747577"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="5"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constImageButtons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF9F00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_register"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbMedia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbRegister"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbWebinar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_webinar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbMedia"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbAboutUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_about_us"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbWebinar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_news"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbAboutUs"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerMouFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constImageButtons"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtComingSoon"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

I need to this :

[image]

I am beginner in `ConstraintLayout` I need to use from `ConstraintLayout` like `weight` of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Please attach picture of what you want to achieve. Also, not recommended to use constraintlayout inside another constraintlayout

Comment: I edited my question .

Comment: layout_constraintVertical_weight will control how the space will be distributed among the elements using MATCH_CONSTRAINT. Please add snapshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @nomag for me match_constraint comes up as a cannot resolve symbol error. I believe 0dp works too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> try below:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtComingSoon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#E1E2E4"
    android:text="New Courses Starting Soon.."
    android:textColor="#747577"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerMouFragment"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerMouFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constImageButtons"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtComingSoon"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constImageButtons"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FF9F00"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerMouFragment"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imbRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imbMedia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbRegister"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imbWebinar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbMedia"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imbAboutUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbWebinar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imbNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imbAboutUs"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: again edited my answer and please let me know if it works or not.
http://prntscr.com/gn0mkp

Comment: Please improve  your answer by explaining clearly what the original poster did wrong and what he can learn from your way.